# How to properly detach Symfony Bundles (pattern)

Tags: symfony, design-patterns, doctrine-orm, bundle

I would like to develop a CMS with ecommerce solution on Symfony 2 and Doctrine. I would like to have a Core Bundle for CMS and some other Bundles I could add based on what clients expects.

My question is how to detach Bundles? I mean there are some relations between Shop Bundles and Core Bundles. If I add them in doctrine.orm.yml files with owning side in Shop Bundle and inverse side in Core bundle, then in situation when client wants only CMS (Core Bundle) I don't want to put there Shop Bundle too. If I won't do it, then there will be an error, that Core Bundle has some foreign keys to Table that doesn't exists.

So how to handle it? Maybe database should be designed in a way that nothing from Core Bundle has connection with Shop Bundles? Only vice versa? Or there is a way of doing it with interfaces or sth else? Any ideas?

Comment: As I already did, I have Core Bundle and Shop Bundle that have no relationship with each others (each bundle only has mapped-super class for Entity). For any specific projects I will create a Bundle (called AppBundle) and then stick these Entities together by extends Entities from Core or Shop Bundle.

Comment: I think I saw this solution in symfony.com docs. This is a nice solution, though it requires to create those Entities each time. I think I could use it, maybe some other solutions? Or taking into account those connections it is the only way?

Comment: You could refer how Sylius config their Entity metadata. It's somewhat complicated but maybe it will help.

They define a parameter for their Entity class, if there's any changes (extend for some attributes), they will redefine it in paramaters config file

https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius